# How to do repeat on all non-numeric characters using the preceding number in the string

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get data from a rostering system. I am not sure if this is just a bad design or if that is common set up but the full day roster is broken down into 15 minute intervals starting at midnight and this is all stored in one field in the below format.

32,20C2L16C

The "," marks no activity so 32/4 means that this person started at 8am, then worked for 5 hours before taking 30 minute break for lunch (L) and then doing another 4 hours of work. I am trying to calculate the hours worked in a separate column - it would give me 9 hours here.

I was thinking that one way to solve it would be to do repeat on all the non-numeric characters to get  this:

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCLLCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC

And then to simply count all Cs and divide by 4. Is it possible to do repeat like this in MySQL? Would there be a better way that I may be missing?

Comment: Storing multiple values in a single column is almost always an indication of poor relational database design.

Comment: I dont doubt that, however I have no control over this. I only need to get the data out to be able to use it in PBI.